# Copying Cells and Pasting into another workbook - 424 error

Tags: excel, copy, paste, vba

I am trying to run a program that spits out data.  at the end of the process i want to copy that data into another workbook.  I  have it set up and working to the point that it copies and pastes the data into the other workbook but i get a 424 error on the past step.  Code Below.

```
sheet = Range("BL1") 
Range("BJ3:BM12").Copy 

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("c:location")

x = 1
While wbk.Worksheets(sheet).Range("I" & x) <> ""
    x = x + 1
Wend
wbk.Sheets(sheet).Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial.Value   - Problem arises here

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Call wbk.Close(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
wbk.Sheets(sheet).Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial.Value
```

to

```
wbk.Sheets(sheet).Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you simoco, I tried the suggestion but get "compile error. Variable not defined"  do i need to define something?

Comment: Is the x1 x and 1(one) or x and l(L)?

Comment: what value in your `sheet = Range("BL1")` variable?

Comment: wbk.Sheets(sheet).Range("I" & x).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Comment: mm..good, but what are you going to say with your last comment?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises when you try to paste from a workbook that is not the active workbook. You would think the workbook you are pasting into should be activated, but you couldn't be more wrong. It doesn't make sense, I know. ;)

```
Sub a()

Sheet = "sheet1" 'Range("BL1")  'changed this for the sake of simplicity

Set cwb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open("e:\b.xls")

x = 1
While wbk.Worksheets(Sheet).Range("I" & x) <> ""
    x = x + 1
Wend
Set PasteStart = wbk.Worksheets(Sheet).Range("I" & x) 
cwb.Activate  'Activate the workbook you want to copy data from
With Range("BJ3:BM12")
   .Copy  
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   .Copy PasteStart
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbk.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Call wbk.Close(False)
End Sub
```

Beware, this code paste values to the original workbook to achieve the paste value effect, so you might want to add some code to close the original workbook without saving.

Comment: `The problem arises when you try to paste from a workbook that is not the active workbook` - wrong. Read [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select). You should avoid using `Select` and `ActiveSth` statements in all cases when it's possible

Comment: Thanks for the Q/A, very helpful. However, the problem user was encountering was because he was trying to paste from the sheet that was no longer the active sheet with no specified range or object after opening another file, so in effect the other file would become the active sheet. The fact that you can use Dim'd ranges and avoid setting active sheet as a better way is beside the point.